# Memory Warning and crash because of UIImageView with Storyboard

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I have a catalog application on IOS 6. So there are some UIImageView in each view.

I think, when I pass to other views, old imageviews are not released. So my Real Mem. becomes 300MB and Virtual Mem. becomes 500MB and I am getting Memory Warning.

I used to use

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    itemImageView = nil;
    scrollView = nil;
}
```

What should I do more? Am I missing something usual?

Update:

I am initializing ImageView like this:

```
    __block UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
```

and set it via AFNetworking:

```
 AFImageRequestOperation *operation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:imageRequest
                                                                                  imageProcessingBlock:nil
                                                                                             cacheName:@"nscache"
                                                                                               success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image){
                                                                                                   imageview.image = image;
                                                                                               }
                                                                                               failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){ NSLog([error description]); }
                                              ];
```

Update:

I am using storyboard. So from one view to other, I am using Segue. If I go back to first controller, viewDidUnload for the second controller is not called. If I go to second view again, memory increases, which means all the image views in the second view are loaded again. Where am I wrong?

Update 2:
I am starting to believe that, it is about Storyboard and Push segue. To go back to the first view, I am using push segue. I create another custom segue that pops the second viewcontroller.

Comment: How did you declare/initialise `itemImageView` and `scrollView`?  Maybe you need to do `[itemImageView release];` and `[scrollView release]`;

Comment: @AleksG I think he is using ARC, so release is not acceptable there

Comment: @NeverBe possibly, but I'd like him to indicate what he's using it.  From the code he showed, those two are class members; so they must be declared/initialised somehow.  If he's using explicit `retain`, then he may need to `release`.

Comment: I suppose you should find leaks in second controller, or post code here

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Instruments to monitor the memory usage, make sure Zombies are off (scheme options). By default Zombies aren't disposed off so your memory usage explodes.